# Python Global Variables for Recursive Function

Tags: python

In my math class, we have been told to write a program in python. In one of the parts, I want to test the convergence of a series. While writing the program, I realized I was fundamentally misunderstanding something about how python handles global variables. Take this code:

```
def main():

    global n
    n = 1

    def check():

        a = 10
        if n > a: print(n)
        else: n += 1

    check()

main()
```

This code fails because it says that `n` has not been defined yet. However, I can't define n inside of the `check()` function since that would just reset n to one upon every iteration! Is there some workaround for this problem?

Comment: `n`  is not global inside of `check()` - you'd need to put the `global n` there, the one in `main()` isn't actually accomplishing anything since nothing outside of `main` is accessing it.

Comment: btw, I'm not sure there is something recursive there as the title suggests.

Comment: There's *also* no apparent reason for defining `check` at all, let alone inside `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, `n` isn't in the global scope yet, since it's inside the nested function `check`. You will need to add `global n` to the `check`'s scope, to access the global `n` value from the nested function:

```
def main():   
    global n
    n = 1

    def check():
        global n
        a = 10
        if n > a: print(n)
        else: n += 1

    check() 
main()
```

@PedrovonHertwig also pointed out you don't need `global n` in `main` (which is the case in your current context, ignore this if you want to use `n` elsewhere in the top-level scope) and that`n` is perfectly fine staying in `main`'s local scope. You can then replace the `global` keyword inside `check` to `nonlocal n`, telling python to use the `n` that is not in the local scope nor the global scope, but `main`'s scope.

Comment: Furthermore, you don't need the `global` keyword in the first `n` declaration, you can just do `n = 1`. This is because `global` just prevents a local variable from being created on assignment in the inner scope when there's a global with the same name.

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig I didn't know what the OP want, just followed his original code. Maybe he did want the `n` to be global.

Comment: Your answer is correct, I'm just adding an explanation and pointing out that unless `n` is defined in top-level scope, the first `global n` statement has no effect.

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig Thank you for your further explanation, I added some text regarding that topic:)